Automate token retrieval using an api generated by swagger-codegen
A snippet like
var config = new IO.Swagger.Client.Configuration();
config.BasePath = "https://SomeRandomBasePath.com";
var apiClient = config.CreateApiClient();

Initializes a C# Rest API that was generated for SomeRandomBasePath, using https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-codegen/.
To set the necessary accessToken, I currently use a snippet like
Console.WriteLine("Enter Authorization Token: ");
var accessToken = Console.ReadLine();
config.AccessToken = accessToken;

which requires manual copying and pasting of the token from the browser developer tools into the command line, which is tedious.
How can I automate token retrieval with a username and a password based on the code above?
There may be a way using the internal RestSharp client
apiClient.RestClient.Authenticator = 

But I could not figure out, how.
